# How many solution for the inequality $n_1\varepsilon+n_2 \leq T$?

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

Combinatorics is not my thing, so I am kind of struggling with this.

Given positive real numbers $\varepsilon$ (typically small) and $T$ (typically big), how many solutions in $\mathbb{N}_0\times\mathbb{N}_0$(or at least bounds) are there for the inequality

$$n_1\varepsilon +n_2\leq T $$

Without the $\varepsilon$-weight the answer would be (if T is a natural number) $\sum_{k=0}^2\binom{2}{k}\binom{T}{k}$, so I imagine that with small $\varepsilon$ the answer should be something bigger.

I was thinking something like for fixed $n_2$ (which should be between $0$ and $T$) I can count how many $n_1$ satisfies $n_1\leq \frac{T-n_2}{\varepsilon}$. Then I can sum it for $0\leq n_2\leq T$, but it does not seem to work correctly.

It seems to be a standard question in combinatorics, but I could find it anywhere. If anyone has any reference I would be greatfull too.

Comment: Why do you think the number of solutions to $n_1+n_2\le T$ is $\sum_{k=0}^2 2^k\binom 2k\binom Tk?$ The correct answer is just $(T+1)+T+\dots+2+1=\binom{T+2}2=\sum_{k=0}^2 \binom2k\binom{T}k$. The fact of $2^k$ is extraneous.

Comment: @MikeEarnest you are correct, I was first thinking about $|n_1|+|n_2|$, where they could be positive or negative. I edited.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say "it does not seem to work correctly."? Because the method you described works.

Comment: @MikeEarnest I was just confused if I wasn't counting the same solution more than once.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:**
$$
\sum_{k=0}^T\left(\left\lfloor\frac{T-k}{\epsilon}\right\rfloor+1\right)
$$
**Explanation:** Count the number of solutions where $n_2=k$, then sum over all possible $k$. If $n_2=k$, we require $n_1\le (T-k)/\epsilon$. For any $x\in \mathbb R_{\ge 0}$, the number of nonnegative integers which are $\le x$ is $\lfloor x\rfloor +1$.

Comment: This is the idea I had. The only issue to me was making sure I was not counting the same solution more than once. For instance, if $n_1\leq \frac{T-k}{\varepsilon}$ then of course we also have $n_1\leq\frac{T-k+1}{\varepsilon}$. But I think it is correct, I am just confusing myself.

Comment: There is no double counting, because each summand is counting solutions with a distinct value of $n_2$.